# Unknown operation while following tutorial

Tags: modeling

I am following a tutorial but he makes a mouth using some operation that I do not know. It is located at a timestamp of 5:02 in the video linked below.

[Youtube Tutorial](https://youtu.be/w5yejofyYk0)

Answer (score 1):

Select the 3 vertices, then press V to rip them.